# How to use bash/expect to check if an SSH login works

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, expect

My team manages many servers, and company policy dictates that the passwords on these servers must be changed every couple of weeks. Sometimes, our official database of passwords gets out of date for whatever reason (people forget to update it, usually), but we cannot identify this sometimes until months later, since we don't consistently use every server.

I want to write a script that will scrape the passwords from the database, and use those passwords to attempt an (ssh) login to each server every night, and send an email with the results to the team. I am able to scrape the database for login information, but **I'm not sure how to check whether ssh login was successful or not in expect**.

**I cannot use public key authentication for this task**. I *want* password authentication so I can verify the passwords.

I disable public-key authentication by specifying the following file:

```
PasswordAuthentication=yes
PubkeyAuthentication=no
```

My attempts at the expect script:

```
# $1 = host, $2 = user, $3 = password, $4 = config file
expect -c "spawn ssh $2@$1 -F $4
expect -re \".*?assword.*?\"
send \"$3\n\"
...
send \'^D\'"
```

I thought maybe exit status could indicate the success? Couldn't find anything in the man pages though.

Comment: Who changes the password? Perhaps they should also be responsible for updating the database. Putting the password into this sort of script seems to defeat the purpose of changing the password frequently.

Comment: The password does not go into the script. The passwords are scraped from a database and passed as command-line arguments to the script, which makes perfect sense to me. And even though people have the responsibility to update the database, they often do not. This is a sanity check to make sure all the passwords in the database are correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been using something like the script below for a similar task.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Run using expect from path \
exec expect -f "$0" "$@"
# Above line is only executed by sh
set i 0; foreach n $argv {set [incr i] $n}
set pid [ spawn -noecho ssh $1@$3 $4 ]
set timeout 30
expect {
    "(yes/no)" {
        sleep 1
        send "yes\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    "(y/n)" {
        sleep 1
        send "y\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    password {
        sleep 1
        send "$2\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    Password {
        sleep 1
        send "$2\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    "Last login" {
        interact
    }
    "Permission denied" {
        puts "Access not granted, aborting..."
        exit 1
    }
    timeout {
        puts "Timeout expired, aborting..."
        exit 1
    }
    eof {
        #puts "EOF reached."
    }
}
set status [split [wait $pid]]
set osStatus [lindex $status 2]
set procStatus [lindex $status 3]
if { $osStatus == 0 } {
    exit $procStatus
} else {
    exit $procStatus
}
```

Comment: I cannot run your script - I get errors like "no such command foreach", and problems with the braces. What shell are you running it on?

Comment: This runs on RHEL5 (expect-5.43.0).

Comment: At the top, do you have something like #!/usr/bin/expect -F? I have expect 5.45 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically need to check if you can obtain a shell or is trying to execute a command also OK ?

If you just want to check authentication, you may want to do `ssh asimplecommand` (using `echo`, `hostname`, or something as such) and check if you get the expected result.

You may also want to launch ssh with `-v` option, and look for `Authentication succeeded` (at the debug1 log level).

Answer (score 1):

crowbent has provided you an expect script to test ssh login however I would recommend using [Non-interactive ssh password auth](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) for testing out ssh/sftp. sshpass is much more secured and less error prone than expect.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the underlying problem (password database getting out of sync) is to use public key authentication. For everyone. Do NOT bother with passwords when it comes to SSH.

Successful login could be checked like this:

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no USER@HOST 'exit' || echo "SSH login failed."
```

Comment: See note at the top of the post

Comment: The problem with this command is that - it will ask for password 3 times which is stick points in script.