# Run local Perl script on remote server through expect

Tags: expect

I have a Perl script on my local machine, and I want to run it on a remote server. The following command works fine:

```
ssh user@ipaddress "perl - --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2" < /path/to/local/script.pl
```

The thing is that a prompt shows up to ask me for the password, and I don't want that.

I looked around the net, and found 3 solutions:

- Using a public/private key authentication -> Not ok in my case
- Using sshpass -> Not in my company's 'official' repo so cannot install it
- Using expect

I followed this page to create my expect script (I'm new to expect): [How to use bash/expect to check if an SSH login works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282251/how-to-use-bash-expect-to-check-if-an-ssh-login-works), I took the script from the correct answer, and replaced the 3 first lines with `#!/usr/bin/expect -f` to have an expect script.

Then I ran

```
./ssh.exp user password ipaddress "perl - --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2" < /path/to/local/script.pl
```

And I have a timeout error. It was as if I ran `./ssh.exp user password ipaddress "perl"`

I also tried putting quotes like

```
./ssh.exp user password ipaddress '"perl - --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2" < /path/to/local/script.pl'
```

But I have a `/path/to/local/script.pl not found` error.

So can anyone help me figure out how to run a script through expect ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it myself.

Still using this answer [How to use bash/expect to check if an SSH login works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282251/how-to-use-bash-expect-to-check-if-an-ssh-login-works/12284239#12284239) but I replaced the 6th line with

```
set pid [ spawn -noecho sh -c "ssh $1@$3 $4 < /path/to/local/script.pl" ]
```

And everything works like a charm.