# How to connect to a server using another server by ssh in shell script?

Tags: shell, ssh

The scenario is like:

```
SERVER_A="servera.com"
SERVER_A_UNAME="usera"
SERVER_B="serverb.com"
SERVER_B_UNAME="userb"
```

I want to write a shell script which will fist connect to server A, and then only it would be connected to server B. Like:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh $SERVER_A_UNAME@$SERVER_A ...and then
ssh $SERVER_B_UNAME@$SERVER_B
```

But I am not able to do it. It does connect to server A only. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Why do you have to automate accessing a remote server through another server?

Comment: What do you want to do on server B? Do you want to have an interactive shell session or do you have some specific commands to run non-interactively?

Comment: Yes...I want to have an interactive shell session on server B.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find some help with this previous question:

[How to use bash/expect to check if an SSH login works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282251/how-to-use-bash-expect-to-check-if-an-ssh-login-works)

Depending on your situation you might also to execute an remote ssh command and wait for positive feedback.

See:

[How to use SSH to run a shell script on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at ssh `ProxyCommands` that lets you do indirect connects automatically. basically you put the following in you `.ssh/config`

```
Host gateway1
  # nichts

Host gateway2
  ProxyCommand ssh -q gateway1 nc -q0 gateway2 22

Host targethost
  ProxyCommand ssh -q gateway2 nc -q0 targethost 22
```

and then you can run `ssh targethost` successfully even if targethost is not reachable directly. you can read more about this e.g. here http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html